# Load assembly to use Expand-Archive

Tags: powershell-2.0

I write a script that shall run at systems that have only PowerShell 2.0 installed:

```
PS C:\> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           ----- 
CLRVersion                     2.0.50727.5485 
BuildVersion                   6.1.7601.17514
PSVersion                      2.0
WSManStackVersion              2.0
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0}
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.1
```

I want to use `Expand-Archive` that is available in PowerShell 5.0. Since the implementation is done in the .NET Framework it should be possible to load the System.IO.Compression assembly and call the method. How do I access these classes in the assembly and get `Expand-Archive` in PowerShell 2.0?

Comment: You don't. You need at least v5 to use `Expand-Archive`, at least v3 to use `System.IO.Compression.ZipFile` other wise you are left with attempting to unzip using the windows shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't. You need at least PowerShell-v5 to use `Expand-Archive` or at least PowerShell-v3 to use .Net Framework and `System.IO.Compression.ZipFile` other wise you are left with attempting to unzip using the windows shell.

I ended up with a function like this after encountering client with Powershell-v2.

```bsh
<#
    .SYNOPSIS
        Extract the content of the referenced zip file to the defind destination

    .PARAMATER Path
        Path to a zip file with the file extension '.zip'

    .Parameter Destination
        Path to which the zip content is extracted
#>
Function Expand-ZipFile {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true)]
        [String] $Path,

        [Parameter(Position=1, Mandatory=$true)]
        [String] $Destination
    )
    process {
        Write-Debug "Unzipping $Path to $Destination..."

        # Check if powershell v3+ and .net v4.5 is available
        $netFailed = $true
        if ( $PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major -ge 5) { 
            try {
                Expand-Archive $Path $Destination
                $netFailed = $false
            }
            catch {
            }
        }elseif  ( $PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major -ge 3 -and (Get-ChildItem -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4' -Recurse | Get-ItemProperty -Name Version | Where-Object { $_.Version -like '4.5*' }) ) {
            Write-Debug 'Attempting unzip using the .NET Framework...'

            try {
                [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.IO.Compression.FileSystem")
                [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory($Path, $Destination)
                $netFailed = $false
            }
            catch {
            }
        }

        if ($netFailed) {
            try {
                Write-Debug 'Attempting unzip using the Windows Shell...'
                $shellApp = New-Object -Com Shell.Application
                $shellZip = $shellApp.NameSpace([String]$Path)
                $shellDest = $shellApp.NameSpace($Destination)
                $shellDest.CopyHere($shellZip.items())
            }
            catch {
                $shellFailed = $true
            }
        }

        # if failure already registered or no result
        if (($netFailed -and $shellFailed) -or ((Get-ChildItem $Destination | Measure-Object | Where-Object { $_.Count -eq 0}))) {
            Write-Warning 'We were unable to decompress the zip file. This tends to mean both of the following are true:'
            Write-Warning '1. You''ve disabled Windows Explorer Zip file integration or are running on Windows Server Core.'
            Write-Warning '2. You don''t have the .NET Framework 4.5 installed.'
            Write-Warning 'You''ll need to correct at least one of the above issues depending on your installation to proceed.'
            throw 'Unable to unzip file!'
        }
    }
}
```